# Access Google IAP protected API from Angular

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-iap

My application has 2 modules

- Spring boot back-end API
- Angular front-end (SPA application)

Both were deployed in **Google app engine (GAE)**.

I used **Google IAP** for authentication. After enabling the **IAP** is there any way to generate the **IAP JWT token** for the different users within the organization to authenticate the APIs from the web client.

I tried token generating mechanism using the **Service account**. But for my scenario, I just want to authenticate and authorize **users** not service account. I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/managing-access#turning_on_and_off) reference to enable the web resource access for users, but it is using cookie based authorization. And it is not the recommended way for the application such as angular.

Comment: It should be possible to authenticate users, but they need to have a Google Account.

Comment: Read this article to see how OAuth Tokens are created. This shows the steps using curl. https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/ You will want to use OAuth Identity Tokens (OIDC) for IAP authorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) to protect your backend api, it means your users have a Google Account or an account managed in Cloud Identity.

In your Angular front-end app, you can retrieve JWT token of your user, with [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

To easily integrate `Google Sign-in` with Angular, I recommend you to use [ng-gapi](https://github.com/rubenCodeforges/ng-gapi) from [Ruben](https://github.com/rubenCodeforges).

Main lines of the workflow :

- Angular uses `ng-gapi` with `Google Sign-in` behind the scene
- Users are authenticated with their Google Account
- You're able to retrieve GoogleUser `idToken` which is a JWT token.
- Each HttpRequest could be executed with `Authorization: Bearer JWT`
- IAP will accept request.

To better understand how to use `ng-gapi`, check this [stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-gapi-example) made by creator of lib.

I also suggest you theses resources :

- [My answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56831311/4786620) about Angular stateless authentication workflow. Just skip the Spring Boot JWT part if you're using IAP.
- [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) official docs.

Note that you need to use the **OAuth 2.0 Client ID** configured by `Identity-Aware Proxy` for your app, and add the correct **Authorized JavaScript origins**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can generate a JWT token using angular-oauth2-oidc.

Get the default IAP Web App client ID and client secret. Use AuthConfig and redirect to your link after credentials are entered; you can capture the token after they are redirected.

This link has all the details:

https://medium.com/@ishmeetsingh/google-auth-integration-with-angular-5-and-angular-oauth2-oidc-ed01b997e1df

You have told that you tried authenticating from service account. Were you able to generate JWT for service account? I am able to capture the JWT token for individual accounts and use it.

Please give more information on how you authenticated from service account.

Thanks,
Bharath