# Access flask backend from angular frontend IAP

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, in-app-purchase

My frontend and my backend are deployed in Google App Engine.

I can request my flask backend from my angular application, but when I put on IAP it's doesn't work.
I've this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend' from origin 'https://frontend' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried to do this : https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto?hl=fr#iap_make_request-python
But it doesn't work. If someone has an idea...

Comment: I found the solution in this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089830/access-google-iap-protected-api-from-angular

Answer (score 1):

IAP requires that the user be logged in to their google account in order to be able to access the resources secured by it. Does your app have google login functionality? If not, you will need to redirect the user to your backend url which will automatically redirect the user to google login page and set GCP_IAAP_AUTH_TOKEN_* cookie in the browser. Post which, you will be able to make api calls to our api without getting a 401 error.

Please [read this](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/sessions-howto).

> IAP relies on cookies to manage user sessions. It also relies on a sequence of redirects to establish a session as part of a login flow. Establishing a session is not always possible if the application is using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to make AJAX requests to an IAP-protected application.

> To successfully make a CORS request to an IAP-protected application, an IAP session needs to be established out-of-band. Note that for an AJAX request that sends a CORS request from source_domain->target_domain where target_domain hosts the IAP-protected application, there needs to be a session established on the target_domain. There is no way to share cookies between source_domain and target_domain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proxy file for example we say that you have a file named as proxy.conf.json
with following rules

Let's say you want to hit an api with url: http://backend/api/*
So you put redirect you /api request to your backend server

```
{"/api": {

    "target": {
        "host": "url_of _your_backend_server",
        "protocol": "http:",
        "port": port_number_on_which_server_is_running
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false
}}
```

After you save you config file, serve your angular app with this proxy file

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Feel free to ask if you face any issue

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't change anything, my problem is the same. IAP refuse the connexion of my front to my backend.

Comment: Sure: 
`{"/users": {

    "target": {
        "host": "https://backend.ew.r.appspot.com",
        "protocol": "https:"
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false
}}`

I haven't got port number for my backend just the app engine url

Comment: For https server default post is 443, so here is your config file

`
{"/users": {
    "target": {
        "host": "backend.ew.r.appspot.com",
        "protocol": "https:",
        "port": 443
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false
}}

`

Comment: Thank you, but nothing change... I think the problem is more on the backend who don't autorize the front to do a request... If i request the backend by my navigator with the url it's ok but with the front i have always the cors policy problem.

Comment: Can you mention url to you api?

Comment: No sorry... but if y put https://my-url.com/users for exemple i have a json object

Comment: Then it should work, I work on apis and this is the method to use, I didn't understand if something else wrong.

Comment: Have you set jwt on your angular app ? or something to identify a service or something else on your backend ? The problem is IAP without that all works fine.