# How to add social login functionality using angular and spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-social-login

How do I add social login functionality in angular and spring boot application.I googled so many time I did not get a proper guidance.Please let me if anybody have done this already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to provide social login feature to your app. The integration with Angular is easy via [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) library.

See [official doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md) for authentication.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user; else showLogin">
      <h1>Hello {{ user.displayName }}!</h1>
      <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
    </div>
    <ng-template #showLogin>
      <p>Please login.</p>
      <button (click)="login()">Login with Google</button>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }
  login() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout() {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Then on backend side, with Spring Boot, you can use `JWT` stateless authentication by validating token received from your Angular app.

I recommend you to read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56831311/4786620) to similar question. The case is focused on Google Sign-in, but the main lines are similar.

**The general idea is :***

- frontend authenticates user via Firebase Auth (with AngularFire lib)
- frontend app retrieves Authentication token as a JWT token
- frontend sends JWT token with each HTTP request (with authorization header)
- backend retrieves JWT for each request, validates its signature, and gets payload attributes (email, id…)
- then, backend checks ‘email’ or ‘id’ in users database to allow or not request.

**Some resources** :

- [Google Sign-In with Backend Verification Flow Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56293624/4786620)
   question on SO, with my answer
- [The Purpose of JWT: Stateless Authentication](https://www.jbspeakr.cc/purpose-jwt-stateless-authentication/)
- [Stateless Sessions for Stateful Minds: JWTs Explained](https://auth0.com/blog/stateless-auth-for-stateful-minds/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this may be helpful for someone

```
https://www.javainuse.com/spring/spring-social
```

I had existing login system using JWT Tokens with Spring boot ,So I used the Facebook login only for the authentication purpose